# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "Teams"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I get the following error when trying to order a query by an associated table's "name" attribute.

**Error**

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "team"
```

**Query**

```
: SELECT "team_seasons"."id" AS t0_r0, "team_seasons"."season_id" AS t0_r1, "team_seasons"."team_id" AS t0_r2, "team_seasons"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "team_seasons"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "team_seasons"."points" AS t0_r5, "team_seasons"."goals_for" AS t0_r6, "team_seasons"."goals_against" AS t0_r7, "team_seasons"."games_played" AS t0_r8, "teams"."id" AS t1_r0, "teams"."name" AS t1_r1, "teams"."city" AS t1_r2, "teams"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "teams"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "team_seasons" LEFT OUTER JOIN "teams" ON "teams"."id" = "team_seasons"."team_id" WHERE "team_seasons"."season_id" = 1  ORDER BY team.name
```

**SeasonsController.rb**

```
class SeasonsController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource

def show
    @season = Season.find(params[:id])
    @teamseasons = TeamSeason.where(season: @season).includes(:team).order("team.name")
end
```

Removing the order or ordering by an attribute on the teamseason record doesn't produce the error so I know it's something related to the ordering of the related record. I thought including it was all I needed to do but obviously it's not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try using: `.includes(:team).references(:team).order(teams: :name)`. In Rails 4+, if you want to use the included relation in the primary SQL query (like in the `order`, `where` or `select`), you need to reference it so it will trigger a `LEFT JOIN` and not do 2 separate SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `team.name` to `teams.name` in (mind **s**)

`TeamSeason.where(season: @season).includes(:team).order("team.name")`

Comment: do you have two tables named `teams` and `team`?

Comment: Ideally table names should end in plural

Comment: This worked. Thanks! As a side note, I have only one table named `teams` and no `team` table.

Comment: Then you db might have a team table. PG would have thrown different error if there was no table named `team` in db.